# Stack, foreach, wrong order?

Tags: java, stack, queue

When using Java's `for`each syntax, `Stack` doesn't use LIFO ordering on the outputted elements. Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class QueueStackTest {
  private static int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i : numbers) {
      s.push(i);
      l.offer(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Stack: ");
    for(Integer i : s) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Queue:");
    for(Integer i : l) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Stack: 
1
2
3
4
5

Queue:
1
2
3
4
5
```

Questions:

1. Does this make sense? Is it a bug?
2. Can I guarantee that this will, at least, return Queue elements in the correct order?
3. When consuming (processing) a `Stack` or a `Queue`, is this the best way to do it? Or should I make a more manual loop with something like: `while(!s.isEmpty()) { handle(s.pop()); }` or `while(!l.isEmpty()) { handle(l.poll()); }`

Comment: Have you tried using just a normal for loop?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an interesting footnote [in Stack's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is
>   provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should
>   be used in preference to this class. For example:
>
> Deque stack = new ArrayDeque();

An extended version of your program:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    Deque<Integer> d = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for (int i : numbers) {
      s.push(i);
      l.offer(i);
      d.push(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Stack: ");
    for(Integer i : s) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Queue:");
    for(Integer i : l) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Deque:");
    for(Integer i : d) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
```

gives

```
....
Deque:
5
4
3
2
1
```

So maybe switch to Deque for a more consistent behavior.

Comment: This is a far better answer than the other one. +1

Answer (score 15):

You need to use pop() & poll() instead of for loop. Thats the API offered by Stack/Queue.

When you iterate, you are directly iterating the internal representation of Stack/Queue.

Comment: Perhaps you could go into the reason _why_ `pop()` can't be used.  For example, what happens in other collections if an element is removed?  And 'iterating the internal representation' is slightly misleading (as a bound-size queue is probably 'circular') - what is the iterator really returning?